# ubuntu run python program in background on startup

Tags: python, background, boot

I need to start a python program when the system boots. It must run in the background (forever) such that opening a terminal session and closing it does not affect the program.
I have demonstrated that by using tmux this can be done manually from a terminal session. Can the equivalent be done from a script that is run at bootup?
Then where done one put that script so that it will be run on bootup.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in addition to putting a script that starts the program in `/etc/init.d`, one also has to put a link in `/etc/rc2.d` with

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/scriptname.sh
sudo mv scriptname.sh S01scriptname.sh
```

The S01 was just copied from all the other files in `/etc/rc2.d`